# View not showing list items when revisiting page

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using ionic, angularfire and firestore to create an app to show a list of wines.

From the homepage I have made a simple button that pushes a new page.

I have made a provider which uses snapshotchanges and return collection, this new page is injecting the provider and using

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.wineProvider.getWines().subscribe(wines => {
      console.log(wines);
      this.wines = wines;
    })    
  }
```

to write to a local reference

```
wines: Wine[];
```

In the html file, I am showing the result in a list using

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let wine of wines" >
       {{wine.title}}
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

When I start the app and navigate to the page the list is shown and updated as required. If I navigate back to the homepage and the back to the list page, the list is not shown - however, if data changes, the list is shown again.
Please help me understand why this is. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [**docs**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) it says about `ionViewDidLoad`:

> Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page being created. If a page leaves but is cached, then this event will not fire again on a subsequent viewing.

So it will only load once, instead you would want to use either `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewWillEnter`, which is fired each time the view is presented.

Comment: I tried those - didn't work either. Think perhaps subscribing is not the right way?